# How to join three tables with where condition to get sum of two relational table's amount for 1M data faster query

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, sum, laravel-query-builder

I have three tables: super_consumers , balance_ins, recharges

super_consumers table:

```
id            name
----------    ----
1              A
2              B
```

balance_ins table:

```
id    super_consumer_id  amount   type(1,2)
---   -----------------  ------   ----
1            1             10       1
2            1             20       1
3            2             10       2
```

recharges table:

```
id    super_consumer_id  amount  status(0,1)
---   -----------------  ------  ------
1            1             5       1
2            1             10      1
3            2             15      0
```

I want to get each super_consumers table’s **Total Balance In amount** and **Total recharge amount** by following some condition below,

1. Total_balance_in  amount from balance_in table where type == 1
2. Total_recharge amount from recharges table where status == 1

**Expected result :**

```
[
    'id' = 1,
    'name' = 'A',
    'total_balance_in' = 30,
    'total_recharge' = 15
],
[
    'id' = 2,
    'name' = 'B',
    'total_balance_in' = 0,
    'total_recharge' = 0
]
```

**How can I properly write this Query in 'laravel DB Query'  or 'mysql' ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select super_consumers.id ,
       super_consumers.name,
       IF(tot_balance_amount IS NULL, 0 , tot_balance_amount) as tot_balance_amount,
       IF(tot_recharge_amount IS NULL ,0, tot_recharge_amount) as tot_recharge_amount
from  super_consumers 
left  join (select super_consumer_id,sum(amount) as tot_balance_amount  
            from balance_ins  
            where type='1' 
            group by super_consumer_id ) as a 
on  super_consumers.id=a.super_consumer_id
left join ( select super_consumer_id,sum(amount) as tot_recharge_amount  
            from recharges  
            where `status`='1' 
            group by super_consumer_id ) as b 
on  super_consumers.id=b.super_consumer_id;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/44

[image]

Comment: I have tested your query. Result multiplying somehow.
Please go through fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ac420d/5

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this one giving the correct result. But if I sum 1k row it's taking too much time.

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine. I've tested in 50k data. It's running in 208MS on my pc . It's faster.

Comment: sorry about my low reputation

Answer (score 1):

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    c.id
,   c.name
,   ifNull(sum(res.balance), 0) as balance_sum
,   ifNull(sum(res.recharge), 0) as recharge_sum
FROM
    super_consumers as c
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
      SELECT
        b.super_consumer_id
      , b.amount as balance
      , 0 as recharge
      FROM
        balance_ins as b
      WHERE
        b.type = 1

      UNION

      SELECT
        r.super_consumer_id
      , 0 as balance
      , r.amount as recharge
      FROM
        recharges as r
      WHERE
        r.status = 1
    ) as res
    ON
        c.id = res.super_consumer_id
GROUP BY
    c.id
,   c.name
```

**Result:**

| id | name | balance_sum | recharge_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 30 | 15 |
| 2 | B | 0 | 0 |

Comment: The result showing 60 and 30. It's not correct. It will be 30 and 15

Comment: True. I fixed it and the result is correct now.